# Excel per-point custom error bars

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I am attempting to draw error bars on a multiple bar graph in Excel 2007, and I am having trouble with the custom error bar minimum value. First, I created the graph from multiple series, then I calculated the Y-Value that the top and bottom of the error bar should be placed at, then I used the Table->Format->Error Bars->More dialog and clicked on the custom button. I then input the series error max and min into their respective boxes. However, the minimum value did not show up. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I am using a Log2 Y axis, if that is any help.

Comment: There isn't really enough data here to provide an answer. Can you please put up some sample data - maybe use a Google Spreadsheet. Then we can have a go at resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you've abandoned the question, but here goes:

In a range of the worksheet, place not the *values* of the ends of the error bars, but the *lengths* of the error bars. Use these ranges as the custom error bar values.